# How to calculate no of rows in 2D array using C

Tags: c, algorithm

if the given function is as exp:then how to calculate no of rows in the given 2d array input2

```
void  fun(char *input2[])
{
  //calculate no of rows and in each row no of column 
}
```

Comment: With only that info, you can't.

Comment: int rows= sizeof(input2)/sizeof(input2[0]);

Comment: but it doesn't give required output ?

Comment: That's an array of pointers, not a 2D array. There will have to be some custom way to mark the end, such as a pointer pointing at NULL. Otherwise, no can do.

Comment: @Avneet After passing to function that wont work .

Comment: This is not possible with what you have.  @Avneet That will not work as you are taking the size of a pointer divided by the size of a `char`

Comment: You should pass the array lengths to your function.

Comment: @Avneet That code will not work. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array).

Comment: No, you have only given that , you have to implement that function only , no change in parameter

Comment: the size of that array remain unknown. it is impossible t know it's size directly.

Comment: Search for `null character` in a loop and count , that will give you number of strings  (number of pointers pointing to them ). And rest you can check length of each string by `strlen()` .

Comment: @Lundin any method , how to solve by pointer ?

Comment: the only way, it to put a special row at the end (usually a row with a null value), the with a loop like `while(*input2){count ++;};`

Comment: @Avneet You tell us. What marks the end of the array?

Comment: In C this is imposible. In C++ there's a way because you can pass an array by reference.

Comment: Consider using a `struct` holding the 1) number of rows, 2) number of columns, 3) a *contiguous* array for the data. Better still, use a 3rd party library. You can then pass a pointer to that `struct` into your functions.

Comment: How to implement that @milevyo

Comment: @ameyCU, what you say is unclear

Comment: @milevyo Is it unclear to find `null character` in a string and count if found . That would give number of strings .

Comment: the way is strings in 'c' `char b[]="abcd"` b contains a,b,c,d and '\0' at the end. in array  some thing like this `char *input2[]={"abcd","efgh",NULL};` the NULL marks the end of the array

Comment: @milevyo Well, it was obvious to check for pointer pointing to `NULL` , but you are correct should have mentioned here .

Comment: it also doesn't work
while(*input2!=NULL){rows++;}

Comment: @ameyCU i could see that you where on the right way, but the way you implement that was not clear. the point is to append a null value at the end of the array

Comment: @Avneet Are these pointers `null terminated` ?

Comment: it is given that each row is a string array

Comment: @Avneet I provided a working code for the sake of illustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general no. In C, it's not possible to calculate the size of an array using only a pointer to it.

However, if you're given a limitation, that the array is terminated by zero(^), then you can count the number of values before the zero using a loop. If it is an array of pointers (such as you have), then the terminator could be a pointer to a specific value. For example, a pointer to zero(^).

Without that limitation, you must store the length in a variable.

(^) you may use any specific value, but zero is a good choice for pointers and characterstrings.

Answer (score 2):

In C, array parameters decay into simple pointers, so you have to design your function to also accept the length of the array:

```
void  fun(char *input2[], int input2Len);
```

If you also define an array length macro you can call `fun` like this:

```
#define LEN(arr) ((int) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0]))

char *strings[10];
...
fun(strings, LEN(strings));
```

Comment: You are required to only given implement that function , you do not change function parameters

Comment: @Avneet Then it's unsolvable unless the array ends with a NULL element.

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible to know the size of an array passed to function as argument, in form of `type function(type array[])`, that because `array` is  a pointer to the first element of it. but there is no information about the last element.

to get over this issue. there are many solutions that we can implement. some of them may alter the implementation of the function itself as passing the size of the array in a second parameter. but if we want to keep function definition untouched. leaves to two possibilities:

1) setting the number of elements on the first item;

2) marking the end of the array (usually is an empty item)

it is almost the second one which is most adopted, here is the code to illustrate that:

```
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int mySizeOfArray(char *input[]){
    char **p=input; //p point to the first element of array
    while(*p){
        p++;//int crementing the pointer
    }
    return p-input;//return the difference between them
}
/*__________________________________________________________
*/
int main(){
    char *input2[]={"First","Second","Third",/*Last*/NULL};
    printf("Size of input=%d\n",mySizeOfArray(input2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user2079303 no no bug in it. i am dereferencing pointer to pointer to char, to get pointer to char; then test it with NULL. as simple as that

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't perceive all the levels of pointers correctly. The code is good.

Comment: @user2079303 but still i am downvoted :)

Comment: Yeah... that vote was cast before I falsely claimed a bug so I couldn't have influenced it. I can't speak for the downvote ninja, but I wouldn't upvote your answer because you only posted code and no explanation. Include a few of your comments in the question to explain that the problem is impossible unless certain requirements are met and when your code is applicable and I'll give you a vote.